# AngularFire update data without pulling already existed data value?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Hi is it possible to update data with adding a number  to already existed data in db or pulling initial data then adding number to it is a must  ?

i mean:

```
this.db.object('something').update({

  current:+1      // something like that current value is 0 in db.




  });
```

or i have to write like

```
 this.db.object('something').update({

      current:this.current+1     // i pulled current value before this is working of course




      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating an node based on its current value is done with the `DatabaseReference.transaction()` method. AngularFire2/5 doesn't seem to wrap this method, but you can easily do this from the JavaScript SDK directly:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('something');
ref.transaction(function(curent) {
  return (current || 0) + 1;
})
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, this code interacts with your existing AngularFire code perfectly. For more info, see the [documentation on transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).